# what is this categorical construction?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

This is a terminology question.

Consider two morphisms $X \to Y, X \to Z$. Consider all such "wedges" of morphisms $X' \to Y, X' \to Z$ dominated by $X$, i.e. endowed with a morphism $X \to X'$ (and so that the natural diagram commutes). Let $\bar X$ be the "minimal" such wedge, i.e. such that for any wedge $X'$ there is a morphism $X' \to \bar{X}$ (so that the diagrams completed with morphisms to $Y$ and to $Z$ commute).

Is there a common name for $\bar X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: $\bar{X}$ is the product of $Y$ and $Z$ in the category of objects under $X$. If the cartesian product $Y \times Z$ exists in the original category then $\bar{X}$ is that product.

Comment: thanks! Though that $\bar X$ is in general $Y \times Z$ cannot be true, I think (unless $X$ is initial)

Comment: is it the most specific term? (what I mean is that, for example, products and coproducts are certain kinds of limits, but one rarely uses the term "limit" when talking about products and co-product)

Comment: Well, if you don't demand that the morphism making the diagrams commute be unique then it isn't necessarily a product. You could call it a "weak" product.